# Alternatives for a service like Keybase?

Tags: git, pgp

Not too long ago, [Keybase](https://keybase.io) has been acquired (or "acqui-hired") by [Zoom](https://zoom.us). There have been several people expressing concern. After talking to some, I heard about how the people behind Keybase effectively abandoned their own project, after the acqui-hire process. However, I couldn't confirm nor deny that.

I've seen a couple users of Keybase "jump ship", however I can't really do it that quickly, and I've kinda integrated some of the services into my workflow.

In any event, is there a similar (competing) service? Specifically, I'm looking for these capabilities:

1. Managing keys
2. Easily sharing keys
3. Tool for simple encryption and decryption of data

Further functions which I'm really fond of, and wish an alternative service would implement:

4. Encrypted (private) Git repos
5. Encrypted cloud storage

Things that Keybase implements, but I don't need:

1. Identity proof *(this is one of the core elements of Keybase, but I don't really need it at all)*
2. Chat / Social interactivity
3. Collaborative middleware

The entire social-media aspect is completely irrelevant to me. I've had a quick look at [keys.pub](https://keys.pub), but it doesn't have Git repos, etc. In general I guess Keybase is more sophisticated.

For now, I'm planing to keep using Keybase, but I want to have at least other options.